# Is getting travel insurance in some way more important when visiting Uyuni than other typical touristic sites?

Tags: insurance, bolivia, salar-de-uyuni

Is getting travel insurance in some way more important when visiting Uyuni than other typical touristic sites?

I am currently shopping for Uyuni 1-day tours and often see some seemingly overpriced travel insurance, e.g. from https://www.viator.com/tours/Uyuni/FULL-DAY-SUNSET-TOUR-shared-programmirror-effect/d22256-120560P3:

[image]

So I'd like to understand 1) is traveling insurance mandatory when visiting Uyuni 2) if not, is there still some compelling reason to get it (knowing that I already have some emergency international medical insurance).

Comment: Does your emergency insurance cover you for all the activities you’ll be doing during the visit? Will you be engaging in any activity that isn’t covered eg https://www.insureandgo.com.au/travel-tips/common-exclusions-when-travel-insurance-will-not-cover-you.jsp What cover does the insurance included in the tour provide?

Comment: One possible reason is that many travel insurance policies will limit the altitude you will be covered up to. A visit to Uyuni may be excluded from your existing cover if it is classed as high altitude trekking.

Comment: Doesn't Viator's help centre answer your question? *While travel insurance is not required, we highly recommend that you purchase a comprehensive travel insurance policy prior to departure to protect your travel purchases.*

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo thanks I hadn't seen that. I'm not sure what they mean by "protect your travel purchases though.